# Can't Login Wordpress in Magento Fishpig : WordPress Auto Login Failed

Tags: magento-1.9, third-party-module, wordpress

I'm Getting 500:Internal Server error.

When checked via admin panel below error is showing:

> WordPress Auto Login Failed: HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error Date:
>   Mon, 18 Jul 2016 13:04:28 GMT Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
>   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17 Content-Length: 0 Connection:
>   close Content-Type: text/html

But my local version is working fine.

Tried Updating Fishpig version, but still the problem persist.

**Error Log**

```
Log {main}
2016-07-18T13:04:28+00:00 DEBUG (7): exception 'Exception' with message 'WordPress Auto Login Failed: HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Mon, 18 Jul 2016 13:04:28 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html' in /var/www/html/app/code/community/Fishpig/Wordpress/Helper/System.php:373
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/app/code/community/Fishpig/Wordpress/controllers/Adminhtml/WordpressController.php(34): Fishpig_Wordpress_Helper_System->loginToWordPress('username here', '*******', 'http://54.186.8...')
#1 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Fishpig_Wordpress_Adminhtml_WordpressController->loginAction()
#2 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#3 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#4 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#5 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /var/www/html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}
```

Comment: Is there not a better error that give you more information, maybe in a different error log? Maybe something like no connection, authentication failed, or something with more details?

Comment: When trying to log in via browser:   www.sitename.com/wp/wp-admin chrome is showing : the Page isn't working. I've updated the error log in the question

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544418/fishpig-autologin-not-working-authentication-exception-because-of-index-php) help? Specifically Flush Da Buffer's comment?

Comment: @AricWatson : I've checked that but that code was already written there(may be updated in the latest version), Anyways I've re-installed Wordpress  (Not Fishpig Extension) again. And now it is working.!

Comment: Have you found any solution for this ?